# How to detect Anchor Tags In String. Both <a and &nbsp;&lt;a

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am trying to validate a job post description. I go through the description value field to look for any anchor tags. If they are present I throw a error

```
get description() {
        return this.form.get('description');
      }



  onSubmit() {
    const desc = this.description.value;
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = desc;
    const iterator = document.evaluate('//a', div, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    const anchors = iterator.iterateNext();
    while (anchors) {
      this.toastr.error("To better improve service, external links are not permitted.");
      return false;
    }
....
}
```

My Problem is This code works when you copy and past the value in the wysiwig. If you manually do it. The value comes out looking like this below

[image]

I need to both detect the `<a` like tags and `&nbsp;&lt;a` type patterns using xpath or anything . Is this possible?

**Here is my Revision using domparser. Still no luck**

```
      onSubmit() {
        const desc = this.description.value;
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = desc;
        const domparser = new DOMParser();
        const parsedDiv = domparser.parseFromString(div.textContent, 'text/html');
        const iterator = document.evaluate('//a', div, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
//Still Returns Null for iterator2
        const iterator2 = document.evaluate('//a', parsedDiv, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        const anchors = iterator.iterateNext();
        while (anchors) {
          this.toastr.error("To better improve service, external links are not permitted.");
          return false;
        }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should focus on finding the term `href`, or `href=`, in the string rather than the HTML tag.

Comment: If you feed the `textContent` of the `div` to another HTML parsing step with `parseContextualFragment` of a `Range` or with `parseFromString(div.textContent, 'text/html')` of `DOMParser` you can certainly then run XPath on the fragment and check for `a` elements. Also note, while your `div` is not inserted into a DOM tree, it probably doesn't matter whether you use the XPath `//a` or `.//a`, but technically only the latter looks inside of the `div`'s subtree while your attempt looks through the whole tree.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for the response. I tried your attempt but I am not sure if I did it correctly. I created a Revision section on my post if you could take a look. It would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: I haven't tested whether it works but technically the result of `parseFromString` should give you a document node, not a div, and it makes more sense in my view to use e.g. `const innerDoc = domparser.parseFromString(div.textContent, 'text/html'); const innerAElementSelection = innerDoc.evaluate('//a', innerDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE , null); if (innerAElementSelection.singleNodeValue != null) { ... }`.

Comment: Yeah that didnt work :/ All I got to know is this a complicated issue cause I have been working on it for 3 days now. Taking way too long.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I think you are actually right

Comment: I am not sure how to mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following helps, implementing my suggestion "If you feed the textContent of the div to another HTML parsing step with `parseContextualFragment` of a `Range` or with `parseFromString(div.textContent, 'text/html')` of `DOMParser` you can certainly then run XPath on the fragment and check for a elements":

```js
    const desc = `<p>This is an element with an escaped link &lt;a href='http://example.com/'&gt;example&lt;a/&gt.<\/p>`;
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = desc;
    const outerAElementSelection = document.evaluate('.//a', div, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
    console.log(outerAElementSelection.singleNodeValue != null);
    
    const innerDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(div.textContent, 'text/html');
    
    const innerAElementSelection = innerDoc.evaluate('//a', innerDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
    
    console.log(innerAElementSelection.singleNodeValue != null);
```